# Widget in separate process

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to run my widget in separate process. For it I have mentioned different process name in Manifest file for widget. But that doesn't help. My  widget code doesn't get executed. Don't know if it is possible or not and what is the proper way of executing in separate process. Please help if somebody have done something like this. Thanks.